# debezium schema.evolution:none attempt alter table

Tags: debezium

- I am using SQL Server to sync data to MySQL, and I am using version 2.5. Below is my configuration file.
- I need to use batch inserts during the initial full synchronization. If I use "schema.evolution": "none," it prompts an error saying "Cannot alter table because schema evolution is disabled." If I use "schema.evolution": "basic," even if my table already exists, it still attempts to modify my table structure. What should I do if I don't want it to modify my table structure?  In fact, I don't need him to help me create or modify tables. I prefer to use 'schema.evolution': 'none'
- When i set 'schema.evolution': 'none',error:Cannot alter table because schema evolution is disabled;

Comment: Can you please provide information on what is the source event's schema in your topic that you're consuming and what is the target table's DDL?